# Python Selenium: locate and click with webdriver -> Tooltip is visible, no "id" or "name"

Tags: python, html, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

my Problem is as follows: i try to log into Wikifolio.com with python and selenium using webdriver.
The login works so far (very basic understanding of what selenium actually does).
Also i managened to click away the disclaimer button that will appear.

Than a list of "Trade" Buttons follows, every single one is connected to a different asset.
When i click "examine" on the Trade Button, i get the following xpath from the site:

```
//*[@id="root-wf-trading"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/a[1]
```

or the full xpath

```
/html/body/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/a[1]
```

the according html is

```
<a href="#add_virtual_order" rel="US88554D2053" data-amount="999" data-issuer="1900" data-description="3 D SYS CORP.     DL-,001" data-security-type="620" class="add_virtual_order js-trade-button inline c-btn btn-trade-xsm u-mr-0 u-fs-s" data-main-editable="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>Neuen Trade platzieren</div>" aria-describedby="tooltip436117">Trade</a>
```

the python code that i use so far is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = "*********"
password = "*********"

url = "https://www.wikifolio.com/dynamic/de/de/login/login?ReturnUrl=/de/de/home&_=1632037782306"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\Users\Benjamin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("Username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button").click()

driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/meine-wikifolios/trade/wf00wiking")


driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change").click()





driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/a[1]').click()
```

When i try to run this code the following appears:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2808785f4fd0> in <module>
     18 
     19 
---> 20 driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change").click()
     21 
     22 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
    596             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
    597         """
--> 598         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
    599 
    600     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

What can i do? How can i adress and open the "trade" button?

Thanks a lot and best wishes, Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locator is definitely bad, this is why you are getting `NoSuchElementException`.
To give you the correct locator I need to get in with valid credentials.
Based on the element HTML you provided instead of

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/div/a[1]').click()
```

Try this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-toggle='tooltip' and(contains(@href,'add_virtual_order')) and(contains(@class,'add_virtual_order'))]").click()
```

Also, you have to add wait / delay before accessing elements, something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = "*********"
password = "*********"

url = "https://www.wikifolio.com/dynamic/de/de/login/login?ReturnUrl=/de/de/home&_=1632037782306"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\Users\Benjamin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("Username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button").click()

driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/meine-wikifolios/trade/wf00wiking")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".c-button--ghost"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-toggle='tooltip' and(contains(@href,'add_virtual_order')) and(contains(@class,'add_virtual_order'))]"))).click()
```

Comment: okay, thank you. The "Tooltip" is also visible when i examine the "Trade" Button. Its always a different number like ``` aria-describedby="tooltip671490" ``` Where and how can i insert this?

Comment: okay i found it. I just added one aditional information from that speciffic asset that is stored in the term "data-dscription"  like wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-toggle='tooltip' and(contains(@href,'add_virtual_order')) and(contains(@class,'add_virtual_order')) and(contains(@data-description,'AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1'))]"))).click()

Comment: Good. You know, I couldn't give you 100% unique locator without seeing that page with dev tools...

Comment: i now get unfortunately an timeout error. I added a new answer to explain that. It worked for 3 times, than the timeout started.

Comment: That's strange. How it worked but after that stopped? Anyway, to create a correct locator I need a valid credentials for that web site

Comment: what is meant by that? passwort and username?

Comment: Yup. Need to see the web page with dev tools of my browser. Without that it may be guesses only

Comment: okay can i send it to you with a message somehow?